# UICollectionViewDropDelegate and DiffableDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, datasource

I'm trying to implement `UICollectionViewDropDelegate` with DiffableDataSource (introduced in iOS 13).

- I've implemented `UICollectionViewDragDelegate`, which is working great.
- I set `collectionView.dropDelegate = self`
- I implemented `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator)` (you can even try it with the method being empty).

The app will build and run, but as soon as you start dragging a cell, the app immediately crashes with this message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be updated via the UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource APIs when acting as the UICollectionView's dataSource: please do not call mutation APIs directly on UICollectionView.

So it seems like this method is trying to modify the UICollectionView directly (maybe to move the cells around as you move the item?) I can't figure out how to bypass this behavior.

Thoughts?

Comment: They might really be incompatible. There is a lot about diffable data sources that was not thought through very well, in my view.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this issue? I'm having the same one now

Comment: @matt I think they just forgot about drag and drop. Compositional layouts does not support it very well either.

Answer (score 5):

This is a fairly easy solve. Starting with the UICollectionViewDropDelegate function performDropWith. Please note I only needed a .move and no .copy but you would just add a copyItems() method similar to the reorderItems() method below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
   var destinationIndexPath: IndexPath
   if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath {
      destinationIndexPath = indexPath
   } else {
      let section = collectionView.numberOfSections - 1
      let row = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
      destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
   }
   switch coordinator.proposal.operation {
   case .move:
      self.reorderItems(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath: destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
      break
   case .copy:
      // Not copying between collections so this block not needed.
      return
   default:
      return
   }
}
```

Then we have the function reorderItems() we need to handle the actual changes in the collectionView. One thing to be clear on is that the snapshot (NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<>) and the dataSource (UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<>) are both class variables.

```
/// reorderItems method
/// This method moves a cell from the sourceIndexPath to the destinationIndexPath within the same UICollectionView
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator obtained in performDropWith
///   - destinationIndexPath: IndexPath where user dropped the element.
///   - collectionView: UICollectionView object where reordering is done.
private func reorderItems(coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator, destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView: UICollectionView) {
   let items = coordinator.items
   if items.count == 1, let item = items.first, let sourceIndexPath = item.sourceIndexPath {
      var destIndexPath = destinationIndexPath
      if destIndexPath.row >= collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: destIndexPath.section) {
         destIndexPath.row = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: destIndexPath.section) - 1
      }

      /// Since my collectionView data is attributed to a Firebase.storage set of data, this is where I write my changes back to the store.

      snapshot.moveItem(dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: sourceIndexPath)!, beforeItem: dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: destinationIndexPath)!)
      dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifference: true)
      coordinator.drop(items.first!.dragItem, toItemAt: destIndexPath)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing changes with collectionView.performBatchUpdates() to update your collectionView this will crash, seems that you need to work the snapshot on your datasource (UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource) which as you can read is indicated on the error: "UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource APIs when acting as the UICollectionView's dataSource: please do not call mutation APIs directly on UICollectionView "

Try this:

```
// MARK: - Properties
  var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, UIImage>?

  var entry: Entry? {
    didSet {
      guard let entry = entry else { return }
      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm")
      title = dateFormatter.string(from: entry.dateCreated)
    }
  }
```

where your entry is an struct:

```
struct Entry {
  let id = UUID().uuidString
  let dateCreated = Date()
  var log: String?
  var images: [UIImage] = []
  var isFavorite: Bool = false
}

extension Entry: Hashable {
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(dateCreated)
    hasher.combine(log)
  }

  static func == (lhs: Entry, rhs: Entry) -> Bool {
    return lhs.dateCreated == rhs.dateCreated &&
      lhs.log ?? "" == rhs.log ?? "" &&
      lhs.images == rhs.images &&
      lhs.isFavorite == rhs.isFavorite
  }
}
```

And reloadSnapshot is:

```
private func reloadSnapshot(animated: Bool) {
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, UIImage>()
    snapshot.appendSections([0])
    snapshot.appendItems(entry?.images ?? [])
    dataSource?.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animated)
  }
```

Finally on your UICollectionViewDropDelegate:

```
func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {

let destinationIndex = coordinator.destinationIndexPath?.item ?? 0

for item in coordinator.items {
  if coordinator.session.localDragSession != nil,
    let sourceIndex = item.sourceIndexPath?.item {

    self.entry?.images.remove(at: sourceIndex)
  }

  item.dragItem.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
    (object, error) in
    guard let image = object as? UIImage, error == nil else {
      print(error ?? "Error: object is not UIImage")
      return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.entry?.images.insert(image, at: destinationIndex)
      self.reloadSnapshot(animated: true)
    }
  }
}
}
```

I'm basing all of this on reading and work from raywenderlich.com "Catalyst by Tutorials"

Answer (score 0):

One more thing:

If you're using the `UICollectionViewDropDelegate` method to return a `UICollectionViewDropProposal`, `collectionView(_:dropSessionDidUpdate:withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath:)`, this method will call non-diffable methods under the hood when it's animating the drop.

My guess is Apple never tested this together with diffable data sources. You'll need to remove this method and implement its animations yourself in a different way.